# How to get a Dell XPS DE to recognise the Cypress touchpad under Ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: dell, touchpad

I have recently bought a Dell XPS 13 Developer Edition (also known as Sputnik), supplied with Ubuntu 12.04. I've wiped that and installed 13.10 from scratch. I believe all the code improvements made by Dell have now been incorporated into the mainline kernel, so in theory everything should work without additional PPAs.

However, the touchpad works as a mouse-like input device (I have a pointer, I can left-click and can touch to click) but there is no gesture support. I'm particularly looking for two-finger scroll. Also, the typing cursor frequently jumps about, and from what I have read on the web, the sensitivity of the trackpad may be responsible.

If a suitable device is available, Ubuntu should show extra trackpad options in System Settings -> Mouse & Touchpad, but I just get the usual ones (Primary Button, Double Click [Speed] and Mouse Speed).

Here is a snippet from `cat /proc/bus/input/devices`:

```
I: Bus=0018 Vendor=06cb Product=2734 Version=0100
N: Name="DLL060A:00 06CB:2734"
P: Phys=
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/INT33C3:00/i2c-8/8-002c/input/input12
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse1 event12 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=17
B: KEY=30000 0 0 0 0
B: REL=3
B: MSC=10
```

And from `xinput`:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SYNAPTICS Synaptics Large Touch Screen    id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ DLL060A:00 06CB:2734                      id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                   id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated_Webcam_HD                      id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

And a snippet from X logs (/var/log/Xorg.0.log):

```
[    25.877] (II) config/udev: Adding input device DLL060A:00 06CB:2734 (/dev/input/event12)
[    25.877] (**) DLL060A:00 06CB:2734: Applying InputClass "evdev pointer catchall"
[    25.877] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'DLL060A:00 06CB:2734'
[    25.877] (**) DLL060A:00 06CB:2734: always reports core events
[    25.877] (**) evdev: DLL060A:00 06CB:2734: Device: "/dev/input/event12"
[    25.888] (--) evdev: DLL060A:00 06CB:2734: Vendor 0x6cb Product 0x2734
[    25.888] (--) evdev: DLL060A:00 06CB:2734: Found 3 mouse buttons
[    25.888] (--) evdev: DLL060A:00 06CB:2734: Found relative axes
[    25.888] (--) evdev: DLL060A:00 06CB:2734: Found x and y relative axes
[    25.888] (II) evdev: DLL060A:00 06CB:2734: Configuring as mouse
[    25.888] (**) evdev: DLL060A:00 06CB:2734: YAxisMapping: buttons 4 and 5
[    25.888] (**) evdev: DLL060A:00 06CB:2734: EmulateWheelButton: 4, EmulateWheelInertia: 10, EmulateWheelTimeout: 200
[    25.888] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/INT33C3:00/i2c-8/8-002c/input/input12/event12"
[    25.888] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "DLL060A:00 06CB:2734" (type: MOUSE, id 11)
[    25.889] (II) evdev: DLL060A:00 06CB:2734: initialized for relative axes.
[    25.889] (**) DLL060A:00 06CB:2734: (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1
[    25.889] (**) DLL060A:00 06CB:2734: (accel) acceleration profile 0
[    25.889] (**) DLL060A:00 06CB:2734: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[    25.889] (**) DLL060A:00 06CB:2734: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[    25.889] (II) config/udev: Adding input device DLL060A:00 06CB:2734 (/dev/input/mouse1)
[    25.889] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
```

It looks like it is doing *something* but the "ignoring this device" waves a red flag for me. Also, the device comes up as a hex string rather than being seen as a "Cypress" pad - it seems it should [show like this](http://ken-mcconnell.com/2012/07/22/trackpad-sensitivity-in-ubuntu-on-dell-xps-13/) in gpointing-device-settings.

I've searched for some possible strings in `dmesg` and found these:

```
jon@jon-XPS13-9333:~$ dmesg | grep synap
[ 1412.350563] psmouse serio1: synaptics: device claims to have extended capabilities, but I'm not able to read them.
[ 1412.550727] psmouse serio1: synaptics: device claims to have extended capability 0x0c, but I'm not able to read it.
[ 1412.951089] psmouse serio1: synaptics: Unable to initialize device.
[15884.370843] psmouse serio1: synaptics: Unable to query device.
[17513.516033] psmouse serio1: synaptics: Unable to query device.
[41102.794436] psmouse serio1: synaptics: Unable to query device.
jon@jon-XPS13-9333:~$ dmesg | grep trackpad
jon@jon-XPS13-9333:~$ dmesg | grep cypr
```

Furthermore, I've noticed that I appear to have two touchpad devices erroneously detected. At first I mistook one for the touchscreen being wrongly reported, but in fact that is reported fine. The output of `xinput` above reveals the issue, as does gpointing-device-settings:

[image: Screenshot of gpointing-device-settings]

I realised I'd made the assumption that I have a Cypress touchpad just by looking on the web, so I thought I'd try the Synaptiks application as well. This reports an error and will not start:

> ### No touchpad found
>
> No touchpad was found in this system. If the system has a touchpad, please make sure that the synaptics driver is properly installed and configured.

So for the time being, I'll continue to assume I have a Cypress pad that requires a Cypress driver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fixed using [these instructions](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1048314#c2), found via [this post](https://inthearmchair.wordpress.com/2014/02/12/ubuntu-13-10-on-a-dell-xps-13/). Although the poster in the first link found the fix did not work fully in their case, it has completely resolved it for me.

The fix is simply to add this line at the end of `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`:

```
blacklist i2c-hid
```

This results in only one driver being recognised, which now provides the expected trackpad switches in Ubuntu Settings. Two-finger scroll now works fine.

Interestingly it looks like I am indeed running a Synaptics touchpad - it is still detected thus:

> SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad

and there is no mention of a Cypress device at all.

g-pointer-settings and Synaptiks now both look like they will work (though I now no longer need them). I've not noticed any spurious cursor behaviour, but will continue to monitor.

Comment: This worked for me with Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty and a similar issue with a Dell 9333. Thanks.

Comment: Don't you have troubles with the cursor still? Like a jumping cursor each time you type on your keyboard, making it go back few lines above?

Comment: Yes, a little bit @greguti, but it's not nearly as bad as it was.